# gt-geojson not able to read featurecollection

Tags: geoserver, geojson, java

I have a geojson file with different type of Features like Point line and Polygon as here

`{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[77.61772155761719,13.073458716478362]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[77.64141082763672,13.083156825357856],[77.6400375366211,13.080815937441855],[77.63694763183594,13.075130831420575],[77.6345443725586,13.069111164597734],[77.63317108154297,13.064429100005883],[77.63145446777344,13.060081389098263],[77.63076782226562,13.05774028229298],[77.63008117675781,13.055733601658558],[77.63008117675781,13.054730255229568],[77.63008117675781,13.053726904726465],[77.63008117675781,13.052054644835156],[77.63042449951172,13.049713461978671],[77.63042449951172,13.047372256948787],[77.63076782226562,13.047037797277522],[77.63111114501953,13.046703337153813],[77.63179779052734,13.046703337153813],[77.63248443603516,13.046703337153813],[77.6348876953125,13.046703337153813],[77.64106750488281,13.046703337153813],[77.64450073242188,13.046703337153813],[77.64759063720703,13.046703337153813],[77.65274047851562,13.049713461978671],[77.66098022460938,13.057405836652448],[77.66613006591797,13.063091350956306],[77.66956329345703,13.06743900886628],[77.67162322998047,13.06944559438465],[77.67196655273438,13.0697800237184],[77.67196655273438,13.070448881026385],[77.67196655273438,13.070783309000612],[77.67127990722656,13.071117736521622],[77.67059326171875,13.071452163589443],[77.66921997070312,13.072121016365408],[77.66853332519531,13.072121016365408],[77.6678466796875,13.072121016365408],[77.6675033569336,13.072121016365408],[77.66716003417969,13.072121016365408],[77.6675033569336,13.072121016365408]]}}]}`

When i read as below

```
FeatureJSON json = new FeatureJSON();
return json.readFeatureCollection(inputStream);
```

it read the LineString as Point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your FeatureCollection is not homogenous (i.e. not all the same) the simple GeoJSON parser will not handle your collection, since it bases the schema on the first object.

To read a featureCollection the best approach is to use a `GeoJSONDataStore` from `gt-geojsondatastore` module that handles all of that for you.

```
    URL url = new URL("https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_populated_places.geojson");
    Map<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    params.put("url", url);

    store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    String names[] = store.getTypeNames();
    FeatureReader<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> reader =
            store.getFeatureReader(new Query(names[0], Filter.INCLUDE), null);
```

Comment: I get the GeoJson an input stream.. so do I need to save the JSON?

Comment: currently yes, GeoTools has to read the file/stream twice to determine the schema and then to load the features